# CSS for individual page PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a site in php with account. I want to write a CSS for "profile.php/user" (for example: profile.php/benjamin). I tried to put this line in profile.php :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="profile.css">
```

But obviously doesn't work.

profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['logged'] == true){
    $username = $_SESSION['login_username'] ;   
    $username = strtoupper($username); //il facem uppercase
    echo "Welcome ".$username;
    echo "</br>Press here to go to the home page";
    echo "</br>Click <a href='/logout.php'> here </a> to log out.";
}
else {
echo " </br></br></br>You must login first to see this section ";
header("refresh:4;url=/index.php");
}
?>

<html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  <!--scalare pagina in functie de dispozitiv -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="profile.css">
<html>

<body>


<div class = "top_band"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain `obviously doesn't work`. Show us the full code in `profile.php`

Comment: Also, what doesn't work? Are there any errors in the Devtools of your Browser? We need more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CSS file is in the same directory as the script, it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../profile.css">
```

This is because as far as the browser is concerned, `profile.php/` is a directory in the URL. To get back to that same level, you have to go up with `../` in the URL.

The browser doesn't know anything about the actual file locations, and which parts of the URL are directories, filenames, and parameters, it just parses it textually. `/` simply separates directory levels, and `../` removes a trailing directory level when parsing a relative URL.